# React useEffect not re-rendering when navigating from different page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am in home page everything is dispatched and works fine and when I go enter to next page which display detailed information and when I go back using `react-router-dom` `<Link to='..'>` back to home page the useEffect is not firing It will not dispatch the redux state which let to blank page and if I manually reload the home page it works. So how do make sure that useEffect re-renders when i navigate it back to home page. I am facing the same problem when I am navigating from any other page to home page or any other page.

Here is the navigation routes for these two documents.

```
{/* Product Screen Design none Functionalities Complete% /}
                <Route
                    path='/product/:id'
                    element={<ProductScreen />}
                />
                {/ HomeScreen Screen Design complete Functionalities complete */}
                <Route
                    path='/'
                    element={<HomeScreen />}
                    exact
                />
```

Here is my Code for homeScreen and [image: Snapshot of homescreen]

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const { keyword, pageNumber } = useParams()
    const keywords = keyword
    const pageNumbers = pageNumber || 1

    const { products, page, pages, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.products,
    )
    // console.log(products)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) {
            toast.error(message)
        }

        dispatch(getProduct(keywords, pageNumbers))
    }, [isError, message, keywords, pageNumbers, dispatch])
```

Here on my first load two this page everything renders all list of product which is expected outcome

and when I visit to ProductDetails page and [image: snapshot of productDetails] where in back button i have attached the link to go back

```
const ProductScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { id } = useParams()
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        rating: '',
        comment: '',
    })

    const { rating, comment } = formData
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
    const { products, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.products,
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) {
            toast.error(message)
        }
        dispatch(getProductById(id))
        return () => {
            dispatch(reset())
        }
    }, [dispatch, id, message, user, isError])
```

Inside this return I have link should redirects me to home page and dispatch the product data as expected but i am getting black screen and **error I am getting is undefined in the products const which should have all the data to loop in the screen**

```
return (
        <>
                <Link
                    to='..'
                    className='fa-2x my-3 float-left'
                >
                    <IoIosArrowBack />
                </Link>
```

I am expecting the home page renders whenever I use useNavigate hooks or link of react-router-dom

I tried to make [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-mz9si4?file=/src/ProductScreen.js) .

Comment: How is the `HomeScreen` being rendered? How are you navigating away from it? Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] of all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the question, Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You should also pass location.pathname as the dependency of your useEffect.

Comment: And the routes and any navigation components? We should have enough of a [mcve] to be able to reproduce the issue. In addition to providing all the relevant code in your post here, a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live could also be helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese I have added the navigation code of these two files in the question but Sorry I cannot create codesandbox of this project that I am working on

Comment: I didn't say sandbox of your project, just asked for a sandbox example that reproduces the issue you have. The idea being if we can resolve the issue there then you can take and apply the changes to your *actual* code.

Comment: @DrewReese I have added codeSandbox in the Question. But I have passed the array of data in same file So, I didn't need to use 'UseEffect' hooks though I have commented all the redux code and from the redux same data is passed.

Comment: That sandbox doesn't appear to be an accurate representation of the code you are asking about in your post here. I've dropped a mounting `useEffect` console log in the `HomeScreen` component, and added a `<Link to="..">Back</Link>` link to the `ProductScreen` and when navigating "back" to the home `"/"` page I see the `HomeScreen` component remounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also pass location.pathname as the dependency of your useEffect like this:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```js
let location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError) {
    toast.error(message)
  }

  dispatch(getProduct(keywords, pageNumbers))
}, [isError, message, keywords, pageNumbers, dispatch, location.pathname])
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it shows the same error undefined in the products

Comment: Could you log something in the useEffect ? So we can sure the useEffect triggers.

Comment: it is triggering when i am loading at first but from productScreen after i click back button it is not being triggered . The useEffect is not being triggered when I redirect to homeScreen

Comment: Even with location.pathname (from useLocation) as your dependency ? Which react-router version do you use ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your answer and I'm using react-router 6.4.2

Answer (score 0):

`<Link to=".."` is not an option to go back, it is invalid
you should use history if your `react-router-dom` version is 5
or Navigate if version is 6

react-router-dom v5

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const App =()=>{
const history=useHistory()
return(
  <IoIosArrowBack onClick={()=>history.goBack() }/>
)
}
```

react-router-dom v6

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const App =()=>{
const navigate=useNavigate()
return(
  <IoIosArrowBack onClick={()=>navigate(-1) }/>
)
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI `<Link to=".."` is a "forward" navigation that removes one path segment. It's valid in RRDv6.